# Scala concatenate values into one string

Tags: scala, concatenation

I need to make a string of the values below and base64 encore the string.

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val str = """ "7080001237543" + "1105" + "7080001237543" + "2015-02-04 12:23:55" + "site" + "0032014143" + "2" + "hJSbGEx5M7" """
val ha = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(md.digest(str.getBytes))
```

However it does not work, I guess I have the brackets wrong. Could anybody help?

Comment: What does you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Which "values" do you want to use?  How do you want to combine them? What's the expected output?

Comment: Since Nazarets answer solved the question, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which values are you trying to concatenate? Why do you have the triple brackets in the beginning and end? If you remove these it will concatenate the rest of the values.

```
val str = "7080001237543" + "1105" + "7080001237543" + "2015-02-04 12:23:55" + "site" + "0032014143" + "2" + "hJSbGEx5M7"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now I just wonder. I need to replace the number "0032014143" with a variable like this: ...+ ${member} + "2" + "hJSaGEx5M7"
But how do I use brackets on the ${member} ?

Comment: Just use the variable name. ... + member + "2"

Comment: And by the way, you can also use string interpolation like this:
... + s"$member" + "2" ...
but this is more useful if you want to avoid concatenation.

Comment: hmm, but this is a parameter taken from a .csv file with the heading 'member'